# How to get Deezer access token

Tags: deezer

I would like to use Deezer API to create playlists for my account, but can not get the access token.

I have tryed `Get token` button on this page (https://developers.deezer.com/api/explorer), but it looks like doesn't works. And I have tryed to create new application (https://developers.deezer.com/myapps/create) - no errors, no new application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I confirm there is an issue with the `Get token` button (of https://developers.deezer.com/api/explorer).

Yes it is a known issue which has not been fixed yet.

You can generate an access token following this method:
https://developers.deezer.com/api/oauth

In order to use the OAuth you will also need to create an application here:
https://developers.deezer.com/myapps/create

Ensure that for fields domain, redirect url after authentification and term of use, specify the scheme with the domain

Eg: http://www.example.com

Best regards,
Cyril